# swift: find-function in generic style

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to program my own framework for organizing data.

I have a class "Root" which is the base and any object functionality should come from it. A function would be for example, searching an object in an array. The search function should be inherited by the child classes.

My problem: The child classes are equipped with further attributes. Therefore I want to implement the search function with generics. The search function should work on the basis of the values in the attributes. For example `Child(id: "one")` should list all objects in the id "one". `Child(id: "one", name: "Tom")` should list all objects with id = one **and** name = Tom.

Is it possible to implement the search function with generics, if the function is to be inherited by the classes ?

```swift
class ObjectController {
    
    func find<T>(data: Array<T>, searchParams: T ){
        dump(data)
        dump(searchParams)
        // Search logic
        /* Something like:
         for item in data {
             for i_attr in item {
                 for s_attr in searchParams {
                    if(s_attr == i_attr){
                        retrun item // found
                    }
                 }
             }
         }
         return nil // not found
         */
    }
}

class Root : ObjectController {
    var id: String?
    
    init(new_id: String?) {
        self.id = new_id
    }
}

class Child : Root {
    var name: String?
    
    init(new_id: String? = nil, new_name: String?) {
        self.name = new_name
        super.init(new_id: new_id)
    }
}

let Obj1 = Child(new_id: "eins", new_name: "Tom")
let Obj2 = Child(new_id: "zwei", new_name: "Tim")
let Obj3 = Child(new_id: "drei", new_name: "Max")

let data : Array<Child> = [Obj1, Obj2, Obj3]
print(data)

Child().find(data: data, searchParams: Child(new_name: "Tom"))
```

### I am happy to receive any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do here is to build an generic "Query" that can tell you whether a given object matches or not. We'll worry about how to build the Query in a moment, but if you had that, you could write this function filter any list to the elements that pass some list of queries:

```
extension Sequence {
    func matching(all queries: [Query<Element>]) -> [Element] {
        filter { element in queries.allSatisfy { $0.matches(element) } }
    }
}
```

Now we just need to build the Query. Basically this is a wrapper around this `matches` function, which is generic, but ultimately is in the form `(Target) -> Bool`. We just need a way to express "some property equals some value."

The tool for that is KeyPath. That allows you to talk about properties and their values without having to know what the properties actually are. Using that, the Query would look like this:

```
struct Query<Target> {
    let matches: (Target) -> Bool
    init<Value: Equatable>(keyPath: KeyPath<Target, Value>, equals value: Value) {
        matches = { $0[keyPath: keyPath] == value }
    }
}
```

You pass a key path and a value, and it will construct a `matches` function that tests for that.

Given some data:

```
struct Child {
    var id: String
    var name: String
}

let data = [
    Child(id: "eins", name: "Tom"),
    Child(id: "zwei", name: "Tim"),
    Child(id: "drei", name: "Max"),
]
```

You can compute a list of matching objects:

```
data.matching(all: [Query(keyPath: \.id, equals: "eins"),
                    Query(keyPath: \.name, equals: "Tom")])

// [{id "eins", name "Tom"}]
```

Note how `matching(all:)` automatically knows the right Target for Query (since it has to match Element from `data`), and will prevent you from any typos:

```
data.matching(all: [Query(keyPath: \.number, equals: "eins"), 
                    Query(keyPath: \.name, equals: "Tom")])
// Value of type 'Child' has no member 'number'
```

You can expand this to more kinds of comparisons just by writing more `Query.init` versions, for example, an `isLessThan` query:

```
extension Query {
    init<Value: Comparable>(keyPath: KeyPath<Target, Value>, isLessThan value: Value) {
        matches = { $0[keyPath: keyPath] < value }
    }
}
```

And by writing new `matching` functions, you can expand this to use Queries in other ways, such as any Query passing rather than all of them:

```
extension Sequence {
    func matching(any queries: [Query<Element>]) -> [Element] {
        filter { element in queries.contains { $0.matches(element) } }
    }
}
```